# How can I resolve this data type conflict in Symfony (embedded) forms?

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to build a form for answering a small survey.

On loading the page with my form, I am getting this error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   VS\myproject\UserBundle\Entity\User. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to
>   "VS\myproject\UserBundle\Entity\User" or by adding a view transformer
>   that transforms an instance of class
>   VS\myproject\UserBundle\Entity\User to scalar, array or an instance of
>   \ArrayAccess.

**I can't see where I would be using the User entity in the first place and have a hard time making something out of this error message. Can anyone help?**

### Additional information

#### Stack Trace

```
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 353   + 

at Form ->setData (object(User)) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper.php at line 57   + 

at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForms (object(CustomerSurvey), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator)) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 385   + 

at Form ->setData (object(CustomerSurvey)) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 477   + 

at Form ->initialize () 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder.php at line 230   + 

at FormBuilder ->getForm () 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php at line 39   + 

at FormFactory ->create (object(CustomerSurveyType), object(CustomerSurvey), array()) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php at line 181  + 

at Controller ->createForm (object(CustomerSurveyType), object(CustomerSurvey)) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\src\VS\Myapp\MobileBundle\Controller\SurveyController.php at line 33   + 

at SurveyController ->takeSurveyAction ('1') 

at call_user_func_array (array(object(SurveyController), 'takeSurveyAction'), array('1')) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2969   + 

at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2931   + 

at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 3080   + 

at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2330   + 

at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
in <myprojectdirectorypath>\web\app_dev.php at line 28   +
```

#### Data model

(entities in [])

[Survey] has one or more [SurveyItem] and can be assigned to one or more [User] as a [CustomerSurvey].

On building the form, for each [SurveyItem], a [SurveyItemResult] is created for the current [CustomerSurvey].

#### Controller

The controller that is building the survey response form (which is based on entity [CustomerSurvey] and embeds all related [SurveyItemResult]) looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace VS\Myapp\MobileBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use VS\Myapp\WebBundle\Entity\SurveyItemResult;
use VS\Myapp\MobileBundle\Form\Type\CustomerSurveyType;

class SurveyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $customerSurveys = $this->getUser()->getCustomerSurveys();

        return $this->render('VSMyappMobileBundle:Survey:index.html.twig', array('customerSurveys' => $customerSurveys));
    }

    public function takeSurveyAction($customerSurveyId)
    {

        $customerSurvey = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VSMyappWebBundle:CustomerSurvey')->find($customerSurveyId);

        foreach($customerSurvey->getSurvey()->getItems() as $surveyItem)
        {

            $csr = new SurveyItemResult();
            $csr->setSurveyItem($surveyItem);

            $customerSurvey->addResult($csr);
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new CustomerSurveyType(), $customerSurvey);

        return $this->render('VSMyappMobileBundle:Survey:takeSurvey.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView()));

    }

}
```

#### Form types

This is the form type I have built for the [CustomerSurvey]:

```
<?php
namespace VS\Myapp\MobileBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomerSurveyType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('results', 'collection', array('type' => new SurveyItemResultType()));

        $builder->add('customer', 'hidden');
        $builder->add('survey', 'hidden');

        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit your answer'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'VS\Myapp\WebBundle\Entity\CustomerSurvey',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'customerSurvey';
    }
}
```

And this is the form type for the [SurveyItemResult] that should be embedded:

```
<?php
namespace VS\Myapp\MobileBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SurveyItemResultType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('textResult', 'text');

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'VS\Myapp\WebBundle\Entity\SurveyItemResult',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'surveyItemResult';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the hidden fields in CustomerSurveyType?  Does CustomerSurvey::getCustomer() return a User object?  This might be the source of your error message if so.  You need to pass a scalar type (ie. a string) to a hidden field, not an object.

Comment: Can you please post the editAction's code?

Comment: Can you post the entities classes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens when you try to map `customer` object and `survey` object to scalar values (as integers):

```
    $builder->add('customer', 'hidden');
    $builder->add('survey', 'hidden');
```

To avoid this issue, change this to:

```
    $user = $builder->create('customer', 'hidden');
    $user->addViewTransformer(new IdToObjectTransformer($entityManager, 'FQCN of User model'));

    $survey = $builder->create('survey', 'hidden');
    $survey->addViewTransformer(new IdToObjectTransformer($entityManager, 'FQCN of Survey model'));

    $builder->add($user);
    $builder->add($survey);
```

Example of IdToObjectTransformer class https://gist.github.com/korotovsky/eeedb6e5d8f6bd9dca38

For more information about Data Transformers, please read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers

It's really powerful thing in Symfony2.